# How to count number of employees with particular name in this query?

Tags: sql-server

```
select table1.empname
      ,table11.empname
      ,table11.timeordertook
      ,Table1.saleApproved
      ,Table1.saleStatus
from Table1, table11 
where Table1.empName = Table11.empName
```

I want to count the number of employees with particular Name in this query  How to do this using ms sql query?

Comment: Don't use the old Sybase SQL syntax `FROM table1, table11 WHERE table1.empName = table11.empName`. It's so much harder to read.

Comment: Did you do a research and didn't find a way to do it? Do you need to count employees who are in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
select count(*)
from Table1
inner join table11 on Table1.empName = Table11.empName
where Table1.empName = 'Some name'
```

Comment: select count(*),table1.empname,table11.empname,table11.timeordertook


from Table1


inner join table11 on Table1.empName = Table11.empName
group by Table1.empName........Sir Now this is giving this error.....Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'table11.empName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: That is because you need to add the nonaggregate columns to a group by.

Comment: I think you should ask exactly what you need and the data structure, because otherwise we will be shooting in the dark.
If you use `GROUP BY`, every column that's in the `SELECT` but not in an aggregate function (like `SUM`, `MAX`, etc.) must go in the `GROUP BY`. In your case, you should use `group by table1.empname,table11.empname,table11.timeordertook`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Just Pass the employee name in the filter

declare @t table (Employee varchar (20))
insert into @t VALUES ('ale')
insert into @t VALUES ('ale')
insert into @t VALUES ('leg')

select count(*) 
from @t
where Employee like 'ale' 
--OR
--where Employee = 'ale'